# Java casting and polymorphism

Tags: java, casting, polymorphism

```
public class A {
  public void x()
  {
    System.out.println("A");
  }
}

public class B extends A {
  public void x()
  {
    System.out.println("B");
  }
}

B b = new B();
A a = (A) b;
a.x();
```

This code prints "B". Could you tell me why? I thought that it would print "A".

Comment: Because you're calling the method on an object of type `B`

Comment: You already used the term `polymorphism` in your headline. Google it and you will find tons of tutorials on that topic.

Answer (score 4):

`B b` is a *reference* to the new object you created `new B()`

When you cast the *reference* from a `B` to an `A`, the object is unaltered and untouched and it does exactly the same thing when you call the *overridden* method `x()`

Answer (score 1):

Just add this one line in your code and check : `System.out.println(a.getClass());` . It prints `class B` .

```
    B b = new B();
    A a = (A) b;
    a.x();
    System.out.println(a.getClass()); // prints Class B
```

So basically, even if you cast b to (A), the method being called will be of `B`. That's *polymorphism*. Look at the *object*, provided the *reference* meets the contract.

Answer (score 1):

Thats because :

This will create a new object of class B with object reference b

```
B b = new B();
```

In this u `a` is the object reference of `Class A` ,and you are using `a=b` so it means that `a` will refer to the same object that `b` is reffering that is the object of `Class B` so thats why it goes into the method of `Class B` and prints B

```
A a = (A) b;
a.x();
```

Answer (score 0):

while casting the object, we have following posibilities..
 1.parent=child 
 2. child=(child)Parent

```
public class C {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    B b = new B(); // b is child
    TestPoly t= new TestPoly(); // t is parent
    t=(TestPoly)b;//parent=(parent)child   i.e parent=child
    t.x(); // return B


     b=(B)t; //child=(child)parent i.e  b=t
     b.x(); // return B (because your calling child.x())


     B b1 = new B();//child
     TestPoly a = (TestPoly) b1;//p=(p)c; ie= p=child
     a.x(); //return B
}

}
```